# PYTHON: Simple Float conversion not working why?

Tags: python, valueerror

Why this simple conversion does not work beats me Please help:

```
print(getx)

Date
2017-12-08   -4.484884
Name: CCI, dtype: float64

chkccisplt=getx
type(getx)
chksplt=str(getx)
type(chksplt)
print(chksplt)
Date
2017-12-08   -4.484884
Name: CCI, dtype: float64
chkdt,chkcci=chksplt.split("  ")
print(chkdt)
Date
2017-12-08
print(chkcci)
-4.484884
Name: CCI, dtype: float64
chkcci=chkcci.strip()
chkcciflt=float(chkcci)

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-4.484884\nName: CCI, dtype: 
float64'**
```

In the last line above the Value Error is thrown back. 
A Thousand Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Comment: read error message again. String `'-4.484884\nName: CCI, dtype: 
float64'` is not correct float number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
chkcci=chkcci.strip()
```

to

```
chkcci=chkcci.split('\n')[0].strip()
```

You need to remove the 'Name:' part to convert the data to float.

Comment: Yagccept answer saar.